# Preventing omitted text in translations due to OpenAI server errors

Tags: openai-api, chatgpt-api

What is the best approach to handling OpenAI errors that are the result of server load issues?

I'm developing a small translation plugin for WordPress. Never mind the other issues that this has; my main issue is the sheer amount of `server_error` errors with the message "The server had an error while processing your request. Sorry about that!". ([See](https://community.openai.com/t/openai-api-error-the-server-had-an-error-while-processing-your-request-sorry-about-that/53263/25))

What is the best approach to handling these errors, given the fact that I don't want my translations riddled with omitted text? Of course I can try again, but this might result in yet another failed attempt. The best I can think of is build an error handler that does exactly that, but to me it seems like this is not really helping OpenAI migitate the load...

Any other thoughts? Save all the omitted blocks 'till the end and only try to fix it then? Seems hardly any different, though.

(I don't quite get why I don't see this error [in the list of possible errors](https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/error-codes/api-errors) either, but that's probably just my inability to read documentation properly.)